# How to assign value to variable using cut?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

Below is the command I am using to assign "yellow" to the variable yellow. I can seem to echo it out using xargs but when I assign it to yellow and then try to echo it out it prints a blank line.

Below is the command. Your help is highly appreciated!

```
cut -c 2- color.txt | xargs -I  {}  yellow={};
```

Comment: Why do you need `cut`? what's wrong with `read -r yellow < color.txt; yellow=${yellow:1}`?

Answer (score 4):

No need for `xargs` here:

```
yellow=$(cut -c 2- color.txt)
```

Because `xargs` runs as a subprocess, you can't actually do anything that changes the state of your shell from it -- even if you start a new shell, that shell's variables and other local state disappear when it exits. Shell assignments thus don't make sense as subcommands passed to xargs.

---

That said, you don't really need `cut` either. In native bash, using no subprocesses or external tools:

```
read color <color.txt
yellow=${color:1}
```

(The `1` is the same column that was `2` in cut, as [bash PE expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) start with the first character as `0`).

Answer (score 4):

Use [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst):

```
yellow=$(cut -c 2- color.txt)
```

The `$()` syntax expands to the output of the command, which is then assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
yellow=$(cut -c 2- color.txt)
```

`xargs` needs to execute an external shell binary and `yellow={}` is not really a binary.